# React DOM not re-rendering accordingly to setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a part of a React application where a todo can be created, with the following JSX code:

```
<form>
    <div>
        <label htmlFor="subject">Subject: </label>
        <input type="text" value={todo.subject} onChange={e => handleInput(e, 'subject')} name="subject" id="subject"></input>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label htmlFor="duedate">Due date: </label>
        <input type="date" value={todo.duedate} onChange={e => handleInput(e, 'duedate')} name="duedate" id="duedate"></input>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label htmlFor="description">Description: </label>
        <textarea value={todo.description} onChange={e => handleInput(e, 'description')} name="description" id="description"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label htmlFor="sidenote">Sidenotes: </label>
        <textarea value={todo.sidenote} onChange={e => handleInput(e, 'sidenote')} name="sidenote" id="sidenote"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" onClick={e => handleSubmit(e)}>Submit</button>
</form>
```

The `todo` state and `handleInput` are defined as follows:

```
const [todo, setTodo] = useState({
    'subject': '',
    'duedate': '',
    'description': '',
    'sidenote': ''
});

const handleInput = (e, field) => {
    e.persist();
    setTodo(prevTodo => {
        prevTodo[field] = e.target.value;
        return prevTodo;
    });
}
```

By running `console.log(todo)` after input changes, I can confirm that the state updates properly; however, these state changes are not rendered as the `value` for the input elements. Conversely, changing `handleInput` to the following solved the problem:

```
const handleInput = (e, field) => {
    e.persist();
    setTodo(prevTodo => {
        let newTodo = {...prevTodo};
        newTodo[field] = e.target.value;
        return newTodo;
    });
}
```

Considering that both functions correctly updated the `todo` state, what has caused the latter function to work but not the former one?

Comment: In the first example, React doesn't know that state has changed.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to write in the Form this.state.todo.subject, something in that sense?

Comment: @ksav Why is that? Since ```prevTodo``` is a pass by reference and I updated one of its key-value pairs, shouldn't it return an updated state?

Comment: @CyberMessiah I'm using functional react and not classes, so I don't think the ```this.state``` syntax is applicable here.

Comment: First the state is mutated, so the rerender did happen. In second you have created an immutable object using the spread operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, in your case you have to return a shallow copy object rather than just modify the key of the current reference state since React won't compare deep in key, it just compares by `===` to check if current state & next state is different then decide to re-render or not, you can also re-write to be working also:

```js
const handleInput = (e, field) => {
   e.persist();
   setTodo(prevTodo => {
      return {
        ...prevTodo,
        [field]: e.target.value,
      }
   });
}
```

Comment: Does this mean React is just comparing the reference of the state to determine if a re-render is necessary, so I should never attempt to directly modify the ```prevState``` object?